# titanium studio - Missing App Id (example: com.companyname.appname)

Tags: mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to create a new mobile project and I get this error no matter what I put in as the project name.  It only happens with the mobile project.  Haven't seen anything on google.  Is this a paid feature on Titanium?

Comment: can you show what you tiapp.xml looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enter an app name in that format.

So 3 parts, starting with com. Then replace companyname with your company name, or personal name, and replace appname with the name you want your app to be. Keep the dots where they are.

Comment: I tried with com.faraway.helloworld and I can´t create project. Any idea??

Comment: @MathewRock why doesn't it work? What error does it give? It should be a valid name

Comment: I fixed. The problem was space sorry